# Set Widget Configuration Icon - Homescreen - Widget - Icon 

Tags: android, configuration, icons, widget, set

once again me ;=)

I'm trying to set a specific (different than the launcher) icon to my widget configuration.
It shows when pressing on your homescreen:
LongClick -> Widgets -> Icon + Widget Config Title

I tried to set it via Manifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".xxx"
                 android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
                 android:icon="@drawable/widget_icon_link"
```

but has no effect at all.
Searched but ain't found nothing yet.

Thankful for any advice :=)
best regards,
mike :)

Comment: isn't this possible? is it too easy to -don't know- ? anything, any confirmation, answer would be great ;)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. I tried adding the label and the icon to the "@xml/widget_info" file (the android:resource attribute in the meta-data of the receiver for the widgets im the Manifest.xml.
Didn't work.

Then I saw your post, and noticed that you put it in the activity. So I played with it, and finally realized that it should be in the receiver itself:

```
<receiver android:name=".WidgetProvider"
  android:label="@string/widget_label" android:icon="@drawable/widget_icon">
  ...
```

This works like magic.

Yair

[kwazi is blogging](http://blog.kwazi.co.il)